# Identifiying primary electron window

Tags: electron

I have some code that is shared between multiple renderers in Electron. I want those renderers to know whether they are the main window or one of the child windows. I'm wondering if there's a quick way for an renderer to know what it's ID is.

Currently I am using the following to determine when a renderer is the main one or not.

In renderer javascript

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';
const isMainRenderer = ipcRenderer.sendSync('main-renderer-check');
```

In main/background javascript

```
ipcMain.on('main-renderer-check', (event) => {
    event.returnValue = event.sender.id === 2;
});
```

This works, but it seems a bit of a convoluted way to work this out.

Is there another way that is more direct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Electron's documentation on [`ipcRenderer`, the `event.sender.id` property](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#eventsenderid) is equal to the ID of the `webContents` from which the message originated.

Therefore it should be possible to retrieve the current window's unique ID via its `WebContents` using [Electron's `remote` module](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote):

```js
import { remote } from 'electron';
const isMainRenderer = remote.getCurrentWebContents ().id === 2;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been scouring the docs but I must have just kept reading past that bit.